# Mvc.JQuery.DataTables with DataTable stored procedures

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables

As a 'fill in the gap' project, I get to explore a new application to display internal reports. The reports are driven from stored procedures that return System.Data.DataTable objects.  Because I've got a lot of leeway with this, I'm using all the shiny I can, MVC 5, Bootstrap, and jQuery.DataTables, but I can't actually touch the stored procedures.

All the examples I can find about Mvc.Jquery.DataTables NuGet package allude to model binding and IQueryable objects.  Is there any way for me to bind my returned DataTable objects as the model in order to use the 'native' MVC support of the package, or am I better off skipping the package completely and sticking with pure .js file inclusion?

Comment: Short answer is no. Create a model to represent your data.

Comment: Thanks, its easy enough to pass the DataTable as the Model and use pure .js to format on the view side, we'll leave the Mvc nuget package until another project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of Mvc.JQuery.Datatables.

I'm assuming your sprocs take parameters to do paging, and your DataTable objects are represent a page. If so, you can use my other project [LinqToAnthing](https://github.com/mcintyre321/LinqToAnything) to wrap the sproc calls as IQueryables.

If the datatables contain everything, I would have thought
you can use a Select statement then .AsQueryable.